# Can't pass data to Dynatree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I can't pass data to Dynatree.

I have a JS object:
[image]

I am doing

```
 var data=JSON.stringify(treeData);
```

I am getting this JSON string:

```
"{"data":"Banner","attr":{"Id":"1","ParentId":"","RootId":"1","Level":"0","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[{"data":"BWS","attr":{"Id":"54","ParentId":"1","RootId":"1","Level":"1","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[{"data":"BWS ID","attr":{"Id":"117","ParentId":"54","RootId":"1","Level":"2","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[{"data":"New node","attr":{"Id":"122","ParentId":"117","RootId":"1","Level":"3","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[{"data":"New node","attr":{"Id":"125","ParentId":"122","RootId":"1","Level":"4","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[{"data":"New node","attr":{"Id":"127","ParentId":"125","RootId":"1","Level":"5","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[]}]},{"data":"New node","attr":{"Id":"126","ParentId":"122","RootId":"1","Level":"4","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[{"data":"ghj","attr":{"Id":"146","ParentId":"126","RootId":"1","Level":"5","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[]}]}]},{"data":"BWS DD","attr":{"Id":"123","ParentId":"117","RootId":"1","Level":"3","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[]},{"data":"BWS FF","attr":{"Id":"157","ParentId":"117","RootId":"1","Level":"3","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[]},{"data":"BWS OO","attr":{"Id":"162","ParentId":"117","RootId":"1","Level":"3","Operation":"0"},"state":"closed","children":[]}]}]}]}"
```

**Edit**

1) I am getting this error:

```
"Uncaught invalid data type for {"data":"Banne ...."
```

2) I have tried `var data="["+JSON.stringify(treeData)+"]";` , but it didn't work and it's not showing anything.

Comment: remove first and last `"` (double quotes) and try.

Comment: I did, but same result.

Comment: I replaced the first & last `"` from your JSON string with `'`, did `JSON.parse` on it and was able to access all `children` in the data.